# Do Russian forces now have an official religious prayer to protect against "Devil's Drones"?

Tags: religion, military, russia, russo-ukrainian-war

It's been shown in some [Ukrainian videos](https://www.reddit.com/r/CombatFootage/comments/1atwl14/ua_drone_team_bulava_72nd_mech_brigade_attacks/) [NSFW!] and also [claimed](https://twitter.com/sambendett/status/1737813766824206790) on Twitter (quoting the latter) that:

> Russian forces now have an official religious prayer to Saint Barbara (who is revered in Eastern Orthodoxy as a protector against sudden and violent death) to protect against "Devil's Drones."
>
> [image: St. Barbara with wings and a drone with a skull on it]

Russian text in the image, with formatting of the original:

```
Молитва от бесовских дронов

Святая Варвара, великомученица и 
покровительница,
Призри на нас, скорбящих и страждущих,
От бесовских беспилотников, что сеют 
смерть и разрушение,
Укрепи нас в вере и надежде, дай нам 
силы и мужество, 
Чтобы не унывать и не отчаиваться в 
борьбе за правду и свободу. 
Заступница наша, моли Бога о нас, чтобы 
Он пощадил нас 
И избавил нас от злого навета врагов 
наших. 
Аминь.
```

the claimed translation is:

> Prayer From Demonic Drones
>
> HOLY BARBARA, GREAT MARTYR and PATRONESS,
>
> LOOK AT US, WHO ARE MOURNING AND SUFFERING,
> FROM THE DEMONIC DRONES THAT SOW DEATH AND DESTRUCTION
> STRENGTHEN US IN FAITH AND HOPE, GIVE US STRENGTH AND COURAGE
> NOT TO BE DESEASED AND NOT TO DESPAIR IN FIGHT FOR TRUTH AND FREEDOM.
> OURINTERCESSOR, PRAY TO GOD FOR US, SO THAT HE WILL SPARE US
> AND DELIVERED US FROM THE EVIL SCALE OF ENEMIES
>
> Amen

Is that a real prayer brochure given to Russian forces? And how "official" is it?

Comment: I can't prove a negative, but every mention I see is dated Devember 2023. No later mentions suggest the book either does not exist, was not mass-printed or circulated.

Comment: What does it say? I can only understand the last word on each page. On the left it is about drones. Has Russia coined that term from The West? On the right it is Amen from Latin, Greek, Hebrew.

Comment: @WeatherVane: there's a translation of the text on the right in the Reddit link, but I'm not convinced it's 100% correct. Anyhow, as you noted, it does seem to say something about drones on the left. The translation from reddit does use the word "drone" to translate a word on the right side too, but more literally that's "without pilots" (i.e. UAV), IMHO. But that's a detail. The real Q is if this is a genuine Russian prayer item or a made-up one by Ukrainian propaganda. I guess it's also possible this was devised a [dark] satirical device, but some Westerners deffo took it literally.

Comment: Having the original Russian in text form in the question would be helpful for research, if someone could make an edit.

Comment: Not conclusive, but if that's supposed to be Saint Barbara holding the drone on the left, it's a very unusual image, because saints (as opposed to angels) are rarely depicted with wings - apparently [John the Baptist is a notable exception to this rule](https://iconreader.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/why-does-john-the-baptist-have-wings-in-orthodox-icons/). I suspect Poe's Law here: it's a creative fake which someone has found and taken too seriously. Finding some other versions of that drawing separate from the prayer might lead to some clues to its origin.

Comment: @IMSoP interesting angle: a google image search for Saint Barabara shows none with wings, although several show her holding a peacock feather. This image also suggests sitting on a cloud – perhaps the author has confused saints with angels.

Comment: Is this the only photo of the item? Could have some publisher info on the back, if it's printed in any meaningful quantity.

Comment: @IMSoP yeah, the saint being depicted with angelic wings, is a big no-no in genuine Orthodox iconography. There's one other glaring thing that stands out: "беспилотников, ЧТО сеют"(drones, that sow). In Russian it should be "беспилотников, КОТОРЫЕ сеют". If you google тракторов, что сеют vs тракторов, которые сеют(tractors, that sow). You'll see lots of usages of the latter and none of the former. I think it's because the Ukranian які, can be translated as которые or что,  since syntax is similar, but not 1:1 and the Ukranian PSYOP officer making this doc messed up. 100% not real.

Comment: @IMSoP: there are clouds under the icon, so it's almost certainly depicting a guardian angel, in the Russian tradition https://russianicons.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-guardian-angel-in-icons/ Now whether that's incongruent with a prayer to St. Barbara on the other side, IDK.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov: alas that's the only photo I know of. 
I do wonder if those prayer card are even common/used in the Orthodox church[es]. A quick search finds [only] some Western ones, which have an angel and a prayer to an angel, e.g. https://www.pilgrimgifts.co.uk/products/guardian-angel-laminated-prayer-card-1 So, it might not even be a Ukraine-made fake, but some purely photoshop production by some Westerner.

Comment: I kinda managed to track down the source of the photo. Ukrainian jounralist  Yuri Butusov https://nv.ua/lifestyle/okkupanty-pytayutsya-zashchititsya-ot-dronov-molitvoy-k-svyatoy-varvare-foto-50378287.html https://t.me/ButusovPlus/6934

Answer (score 5):

No way.

(Left this as a comment under the question, but on second thought, it deserves an answer)

IMSoP correctly pointed out in a comment, putting it in an answer here for greater visibility, that in Orthodox Iconography, saints don't have angelic wings, with [St John being a special exception](https://iconreader.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/why-does-john-the-baptist-have-wings-in-orthodox-icons/) due to his angelic attributes. No Orthodox priest/artist (of which the Russian army has lots on the payroll, including iconographers), would **ever** depict St Barbara with wings.

Another thing that jumps out is the wording of "беспилотников, **что**(chto) сеют", "drones **that** sow", 4th line. In Russian it should be "беспилотников, **которые**(kotorye) сеют". They both mean the same thing, but the choice depends on the declension of the preceding noun "drones". This can be verified by comparing to the usage for a real item in the same grammatical category as drones, tractors. If you Google "тракторов, что сеют" vs "тракторов, которые сеют"(tractors, that sow). You'll see lots of usages of the latter and none of the former.

I think it's because the Ukranian "that", has different declension rules, so it would be які(yaki) either way. Since Russian and Ukranian syntax is similar and can usually be translated 1:1, but not always, the Ukranian PSYOP guy translating "безпілотників, які сіють" from some preliminary draft when making this fake, screwed up. It's a natural mistake for a Ukrainian native speaker to make, but extremely unlikely for a native Russian speaker.

Comment: If the claim is that this is a Ukrainian psyop, then I don't get the point about wings. Ukrainians are Orthodox as well and have the same religious tradition as the Russian Orthodox church. If this was made by a Ukrainian, they should be familiar with the way that Christian saints should be portrayed.

Comment: @SIMEL despite nominally high levels of Orthodox affiliation, the level of deep religiosity is pretty low in both countries and American style going to church every Sunday is def not the norm. I go to an Orthodox church for Easter, every couple of years, to keep in touch with the cultural aspect and that's not unusual. The wings didn't even strike me as odd, until it was pointed out, since in the church there is a giant wall of icons, the look the same in their Byzantine stye, some have wings, some don't. Vaguely remember the Saint vs Angel difference being described looooong ago after this

Comment: @SIMEL episode refreshed my memory, but wouldn't have thought of it otherwise. A Ukrainian urban professional working in Psyops would be in the same boat. But a churchman 100÷ wouldn't. This booklet is pretty standard style, Orthodox churches always have a ton of them in their church store, but they are made by centralized church print shops, run by monks/nuns, or in the church itself, if it's a big one with facilities. Angels and saints are a common theme. There is absolutely no way a mistake like that could be made for a real booklet. Psyops seems like the only likely option.

Comment: @SIMEL The wording is what immediately stood out to me, as I explained.

Comment: I agree with you about the wording (don't know about Ukrainian, but the Russian is def wrong). I don't know about the structure of the Russian Orthodox church, but I see no reason that this made by a local priest at Luhansk or Donetsk, by a military chaplain at a local level, or even as a private initiative by a group of Russian soldiers without going through the Patriarch and his knowledge is lesser. Or, that, since you mentioned there is already one saint that gets wings, then maybe in this case they decided to add wings because it's for areal defence.

Comment: @SIMEL any priest at whatever level or a chaplain must have completed their seminary education to be ordained. And iconography is Serious Business(TM) in orthodoxy, giving a Saint angelic wings if they don't merit them like St John, is blasphemy. In combination with the language error, a Ukrainian Psyop officer making a couple of seemingly insignificant cultural mistakes, is market orders of magnitude more probably than this being what it's purported.

Comment: Even assuming the blog is a reliable source on this, where does it say Barabara is not ever depicted with wings? Please add a quote at least. (Note that blogs can be deleted and sometimes aren't even archived on web archive.)

Comment: FWTW, I checked the 'about' sections of that blog, but it's entirely anonymous. I'm pretty sure one can find better sources for a claim like this.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat Did you even read it? It explains that St John the Baptist is UNIQUE in being depicted with wings, because he was the Evangelos(messenger) of the news of Jesus. Angels are also Evangelos, which is where the word comes from. I didn't find that link, IMSoP posted it as a comment under the OP, I included it with attribution. I'd only noticed the un-natural language usage myself. I have no data on how accurate that blog is overall, but with a bit of Google-Fu, here are a couple more links that mention the same thing:

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat https://www.maryhillmuseum.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/MOTHER-OF-GOD-Saints-ONLINE.pdf St. John's wings are P33, St Barbara, wingless, is discussed on P45.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat https://catalog.obitel-minsk.com/blog/2022/09/why-does-saint-john-the-baptist-appear-in-icons-with-two-heads-and-a-pair-of-wings

Comment: Look (more) closely.

Comment: @AgentSmith at what?

Comment: @Eugene, at your well-written answer. You belong.

Comment: Re: your second part about "что" vs "которые" - sorry, but that's incorrect. Substituting latter with former isn't common, but it is used often enough in Russian literature to add some pathos to the text so that it wouldn't raise any eyebrows in this context. Try searching for "что сеют смерть", for instance (tractors rarely require additional pathos). On the other hand - afaik, orthodox prayers avoid using both of those, opting to use participles instead (so "беспилотников , сеющих смерть" would be more likely).

Comment: This doesn't have the referencing required of an answer. You only have a single link to a blog for one of your points (not the main point), and that blog doesn't really have any authority backing it either.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov will beg to differ. "bezoilotnikEE, CHTO seyut", would be grammatically OK, but not for "bezoilotnikOV, ". It's not about pathos, "tractorY, CHTO seyut", is a real usage. I suppose it could be an attempt to inject poetical pathos, instead of a simple translation mistake, but then it just shows that the author, like with the saint's wings, isn't religious and isn't familiar with the conservative language of Orthodox prayer books. I had a look at some samples online after your comment, and yeah, they all use participles where possible to be more like Church Slavonic.

Comment: @Laurel The wings aren't my main point, it's something that I completely missed myself, noticed that IMSoP had pointed out in a comment under the OP and added it in, since IMSoP hadn't posted an answer and comments are a lot less visible. My main point is the un-natural grammar. As to authoritative online sources, there aren't any. Orthodoxy is pretty Luddite, they mostly do books, not websites, and the theology of saintly wings is a really esoteric topic.  I searched online and it's all like that blog post and the 2 others I posted. But they all agree and there are none that disagree.

Comment: @Eugene, Here they use it exactly as you say that is incorrect "Для падших ангелов, что сеют смерть." https://stihi.ru/2023/10/10/6206. And Here Basta uses it in the form that you say is grammatically acceptable "А те, что сеют смерть во имя Аллаха!" https://www.beesona.pro/songs/basta/za_dushu_beret_grust.php In Hebrew there is a saying "In art as in art, there is no such thing as there is no such thing" and I think that this is the case here. Grammatical correctness can takes a back seat for artistic or religious need.

Comment: @SIMEL these are a poem and the lyrics of a song written in a rhyming style. Obviously, the rules of grammar get broken all the time in poetry to get the syllable count to match for rhyming. But Orthodox prayers aren't rhythmic.